# Cookie not being written in PHP even though it shows in Response header

Tags: php, ajax, cookies, header, setcookie

I'm making an AJAX call on my website to a login page and (trying to store) a cookie using setcookie(). When I see the request headers in Chrome inspector, I can see the correct Request Headers but the cookie is not being stored.

What could I possibly be doing incorrectly? (I am not doing any output at all)

Comment: How do you know it is correct?

Comment: what are you doing and how?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your PHP code is not doing any output at all.  Not even 1 teensy weensy blank character (perhaps just before your first `<?php` tag).

Because if PHP writes even a single character of the response body, it can no longer write HTTP headers ... which is what `setcookie` must do in order to create a cookie.

Another possibility, quoting from the [PHP doc for setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that
>   the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully
>   set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie
>   expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to
>   debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling
>   print_r($_COOKIE);.

(If this still is not it, show us your exact and entire code with `setcookie`. We need more info to be of help.)

Comment: I did double check for the existence any white space being output.. none that I can see! This is an XHR call with no response being sent back to the client (not even a success messagea. The Response headers do show something like:

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://[redacted].org
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:57
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 08 Dec 2015 17:38:34 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=10, max=88
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache
Set-Cookie:userRole=Henry; expires=Wed, 07-Dec-2016 17:38:34 GMT; path=.[DOTredacted].org
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.29

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. This was a part of a complex project.

I had to go and look at the local cookies on my Chrome (rather than in the headers alone, or just using the editthiscookie plugin for Chrome.)

Long story short, there was bad cookie logic in javascript code that was stomping on my cookie, but THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!